# Why am I getting the error java.util.NoSuchElementException from my code below?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm getting this error java.util.NoSuchElementException from my code below and I can't figure out why. I'm attempting to write a code that reads an integer, a list of words, and a character. The integer signifies how many words are in the list. The output of the program is every word in the list that contains the character at least once.

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String[] arr = new String[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            arr[i] = in.next();
        }
        char ch = in.next().charAt(0); //line that launches the error
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if(arr[i].contains(""+ch)) {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you read an empty line? Yeah, you do. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction. I'm still confused on what the problem is though. Does the real problem lie with `arr[i] = in.next();` ?